# ROS Answers SE migration: robot with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i would like to develop a android robot arm using ROS?
Is it possible ?
i mean that , in the ROS.ORG portal, it mentioned that **ROBOT USING OR CAN BE USED ROS.**

whether That sentence meant ROS CANNOT BE ENRICHED WITH ANY OTHER ROBOT ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9577/robot-with-ros/) by [NETHAJI](https://answers.ros.org/users/354/nethaji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to develop for any robot, irrespective of whether it is on the list or not. If the robot is not on that list you will need to develop some custom ROS driver nodes to interface with the hardware, though.

Check the Getting Started section on the wiki to get a grip of what ROS is and what can it enable you to do. http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/StartGuide

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5